# The fastest way to find a string inside a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have tried many ways of looking for a string inside a file, but all were slow. All I need is:

- look for a string inside a file
- print the line on which the string is

All I've been doing until now was reading a file (tried many ways) and then checking whether the string I am looking for is located in the current line. If not, check the next line, etc.

**What is the best way to do this?**

Comment: Use `grep` or [`ag`, the silver searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher)?

Comment: I'd like this multiplatform. Basically something similar to grep in python.

Comment: Have them install unxtools then? Otherwise... you're limited to the speed of Python, and I don't think there's a faster way of doing what you're doing except *maybe* using regex to search the string.

Comment: Okay, I'll use grep. But side-question: Why is Python slower than grep? Because grep is based on a low-level language?

Comment: What is the fastest method you achieved with python? And how does it compare with grep?

Comment: Fastest method, as in code? And it takes like 3 minutes, whereas grep takes like 15 seconds.

Comment: @SamuelShifterovich That is actually probably an interesting question. You should compare timing (maybe including ag) and post a new question with your timings, file input sizes, and ask *why*. (and maybe post a comment here, because I'd be interested as heck ;)

Comment: I'll notify you once posted. .. but, how do I measure time for grep? (sorry, unix noob)

Comment: How about using grep in python and checking the return?

Comment: That's what I meant.

Comment: There are special [string searching algorthims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) that do preprocessing on the target string do speed things up. A naive `if target in line` isn't able to do this. Although implementing it in python might make things worse...

Comment: @WayneWerner https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37079658/why-is-python-slower-than-grep

Comment: If you're printing each line as you find it, try alternatively gathering them in a list and printing `'\n'.join(lines)` at the end.

Comment: @AlexHall As I realize that printing is slowing down the process, it's optional (--verbose) and defaulutly not printing.

Answer (score 7):

The following will work for the fist occurrence of a substring `something`. `None` is assigned if no match is found; file is read lazily up to the first match.

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    line = next((l for l in f if something in l), None)
```

To find all matches, you can use a list comprehension:

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    lines = [l for l in f if something in l]
```

I do not know if you can be much faster than this in pure python.

Answer (score 1):

I tried very hard to get a faster version than Yakym's using itertools instead of plain Python iteration. In the end it was still slower. Perhaps someone can come up with a better way.

```
from itertools import imap, tee, compress, repeat
from time import time

target = 'Language Chooser'
path = '/Users/alexhall/Desktop/test.log'

start = time()

with open(path) as f:
    lines1 = [l for l in f if target in l]

print time() - start

# -----

start = time()

with open(path) as f:
    f1, f2 = tee(f)
    lines2 = list(compress(f1, imap(str.__contains__, f2, repeat(target))))

print time() - start

assert lines1 == lines2
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your target for speed, but this is pretty fast since it defers most of the work to built-in functions.

```
import string, re, sys

def find_re(fname, regexp):
    line_regexp ='^(.*%s.*)$' % regexp
    f = open(fname, 'r')
    txt = string.join(f.readlines())
    matches = re.findall(line_regexp, txt, re.MULTILINE)
    for m in matches:
        print(m)

def find_slow(fname, regexp):
    f = open(fname, 'r')
    r = re.compile(regexp)
    for li in f.readlines():
        if re.search(regexp, li):
            print(li),
```

The 'slow' version is probably what you tried. The other one, `find_re`, is about twice as fast (0.7 second on searching a 27 MB text file), but still 20x slower than `grep`.

Comment: This assumes that the file can be handled in memory.

Comment: I made a typo in the timing, corrected it immediately, but maybe you responded to the pre-edit version.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 version : (code from Alex Hall)

```py
from itertools import tee, compress, repeat
from time import time

target = '1665588283.688523'
path = 'old.index.log'

start = time()

with open(path) as f:
    lines1 = [l for l in f if target in l]

print(time() - start)

# -----

start = time()

with open(path) as f:
    f1, f2 = tee(f)
    lines2 = list(compress(f1, map(str.__contains__, f2, repeat(target))))

print(time() - start)

assert lines1 == lines2
```