# Fastest way to find a file that contains a string

Tags: python

I was looking for the fastest way to find a file, from a given directory, that contains a text string.

I've come across this question: [The fastest way to find a string inside a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078978/the-fastest-way-to-find-a-string-inside-a-file)

Most of the answers claimed that the fastest way to do this is using system grep. But no one added times so I've timed it.

I've timed those 2 functions:

```
mysetup_sys = '''
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
def find_file_containing_string(str, files_dir):
    cmd = "grep {str} -rl {dir}".format(str=str, dir=files_dir)
    proc = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    file, err = proc.communicate()
    return file'''
```

and

```
mysetup_py='''
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, getmtime, join
def find_file_containing_string(str, files_dir):
    files_paths = filter(isfile, [join(files_dir, f) for f in listdir(files_dir)])
    for file in sorted(files_paths, key=getmtime): #iterate files sorted by time
        with open(file) as fl:
            found = next((l for l in fl if str in l), None) #find first occurrence in file
        if found:
            return file
    return None'''
```

And the test:

```
mycode1='''find_file_containing_string(some_string_not_in_files, dir_path)'''
mycode2='''find_file_containing_string(some_string_exists_in_one_file, dir_path)'''

timeit.timeit(stmt=mycode1, number = 10000, setup=mysetup_py)
timeit.timeit(stmt=mycode1, number = 10000, setup=mysetup_sys)

timeit.timeit(stmt=mycode2, number = 10000, setup=mysetup_py)
timeit.timeit(stmt=mycode2, number = 10000, setup=mysetup_sys)
```

I've got these results:

String not found in files:

> Pythonic way (All files were searched): **284.1225619316101**
>
> System grep using Popen: **306.4192249774933**

String found in files:

> Pythonic way (Search stopped at first match, file #61 out of #87 files): **211.5037169456482**
>
> Pythonic way (Search stopped at first match, file #44 out of #87
>   files): **177.46654987335205**
>
> System grep using Popen: **317.99017000198364**

The results shows that the pythonic way is ~7% faster on worst case (string not found, or found in last file) and ~33% faster on average case (string found on file #61 out of #87 files)

The results didn't make any sense, so I tried to add --max-count 1 to grep, which means grep will stop searching within the file at first match, but it'll continue to search the other files.

```
cmd = "grep {str} -rlm1 {dir}".format(str=str, dir=files_dir)
```

> System grep using Popen, String found in files: **314.34678983688354**
>
> System grep using Popen, String not found: **309.60394191741943**

It seems weird that the pythonic way is that much faster, am I missing something?

Comment: The problem is you're using python code vs subprocesses in python. Subprocesses are slow because you're using Python to open something outside, then get its results, as opposed to doing a "same" call directly in Python (which doesn't open anything outside, all calls are made directly by Python, or rather an underlying C code).

Comment: If you want a reliable result, you would need to compare python script vs shell script.

Comment: Consider to use flag -i in grep to ignore case, and match Upper Lower Capitalize etc

Comment: @h4z3 I know that subprocesses  are slow but from what I understood (from asking people and looking for answers on the web) the C code  should be faster, even when using suproccess to call it. Shell script will undoubtedly be faster, but I need to use python so it's pointless to test it in shell

Comment: @Wonka  I've added the '-i' per your suggestion, and the results stayed pretty much the same, _System grep using Popen, string not found:_ **345.6600031852722**. I retested pythonic way to make sure the time difference is not due to computer speed, _Pythonic way, string not found:_ **313.9874029159546**